# How to load a different front page in Wordpress if a cookie is set?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, redirect

I'm trying to figure out how i'd write a function or something so that Wordpress will show the user 2 different pages depending upon cookie.
If a cookie is set, they see a different front-page. Both the pages have to be wordpress, i.e. editable from wordpress, I just want to change page_id depending upon cookie is set or not

1. Set Cookie if user hasn't been on site earlier
2. Show him blog
3. If the cookie is already set show user page_id=9

For eg If cookie is set they see page_id=9 and if cookie is not set they see blog. No user registration, Just the casual redirect in case PHP cookie is set

I can't find the following even after googling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a javascript redirect. Untested, but this should work. Cookie reference from [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

```
createCookie('beenhere', '1', 1);
if (readCookie('beenhere') == '1' && window.location.pathname == '' ) {
   window.location = window.location.hostname + "/page_id=9"
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would probably do this with php, but my js skills are better. I'm sure someone will chime in with a php solution too.

Comment: This gets the wordpress into infinite loop

Comment: You must be including the javascript on all pages then, not just the front page. You will need to put in a check that you are on front page. See my code change.

Answer (score 0):

Put the at the top of the header or in the index page

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['cookie'] ) ) {
    header( "Location: /?page_id=9" );
}
else {
    setcookie(...);
}
```

check for the cookie, if it exists redirect, otherwise set the cookie

NOTE: This will only work in the template page for eg you default(landing page) template is 'Home' put this code in your home template.
It will not work in header.php or index.php in root directory

Comment: One other thing, make sure you do the redirect before any html is output. Otherwise the redirect will fail.

Comment: Wordpress keep trying to redirect to the blog url even if I do above. It goes into infinite loop
`if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['cookie'] ) ) {
   ?>
   <script>
   top.location.href ="http://localhost/Wordpress_Work/nota/welcome-2/";
   </script>
   <?php
}
else {
   setcookie("cookie","set", time()+3600*24);
}`

Comment: You are doing a javascript redirect when he recommended you do a php redirect. Setting the href property is not the same as changing the header. Just like in my answer you will need to execute this code only for the front page, or put in a check that it is the front page. `if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '' )` or something like that. You may need to futz a bit.